# What is firing a timer in an absolutely empty Angular app?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

I created a new Angular app with `ng new myapp`, removed all content from app.component, and went to localhost:4200 - which serves an absolutely blank page, and there is nothing going on otherwise.

When I record a performance session in chrome, I see the following:

[image: screenshot of event in performance session]

I was expecting to see nothing, because nothing is going on in this app.

**Hence my question**: What is responsible for this Task/Timer Fired/Function Call, that even took quite a bit of time (60ms, over 3 frames)? Or how could I find out?

**Update**: When I follow the link in the bottom right, and find find zone-evergreen.js is open, and contains this regarding setTimeout:

[image]

Question still is: what tasks are queued and need to be run?

Comment: There's a link to the source in the bottom right corner of the screenshot. I guess setTimeout is used by the internal scheduling of the Angular runtime.

Comment: So I see my guess is confirmed. As for what exactly is happening, maybe Angular makes some tests on DOM/CSS to install some polyfills if necessary. Usually it's fast but here something's weird, could be a bug in Chrome. Try a portable older Chrome and also Chrome Canary.